# Display two pdf documents on form submit in separate windows/tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have .NET MVC web application. On my page there is a form to choose what pdf docs to display. I want to open pdf files in a new window or tab. The user can choose to display one or two pdf files. My form posts the data to controller, but i dont know how to return two pdfs from my controller and display in separate window/tab.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be done?

Comment: If you are using Adobe as the viewer going to have problems as it just does not automate nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the model write the urls to the documents into a javascript code block

```
@if(model.ShowPDFs)
{

<script>
function ShowPDF()
{
    window.open('@model.PdfUrl1');
    @if(model.Open2Pdf)
    {
        window.open('@model.PdfUrl2');
    }
}

// opens the document after 3 seconds after the page has loaded
setTimeOut("ShowPDF()", 3000);


</script>

}
```

Comment: I guess from here you get an idea on how to continue on by yr self.

Comment: Been trying to do something like that, have not got it yet. I have functions that returns PDF stream so my controller is returning FileStreamResult like "return File(filestream, "application/pdf", "filename.pdf");" Tried to put this into model and made View but that have not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar (but I build the pdf server-side using ReportViewer) in this way:

my form post data to the controller action (with ajax)

- the controller action reads the posted data, query the database
  accordingly to it, and decide how many pdfs I have to return;
- the controller action saves in the session, with a different key for every pdf (determined by my logic), the data to pass to ReportViewer;
- the controller action returns (to the callback of the ajax call) an array with all the key used to store data in the sessions;
- client side, the js callback loop over the returned array and, for every item, call (it opens a link in a different tab) a different controller (whose only responsibility is to send pdf to the request) passing it, in the query string, the key for that pdf;
- the PrintController read the data from the session (using the key received), build the report and send it in the response.

I think you could do something similar; I don't understand how your pdf are built (are they data-depending or pdf pre-existing on the server?), but you can save the pdf stream, or the pdf path in the session instead of the data like me.

Hope to help; if you think that my solution can work for you and you need some code I can try to extract some from my codebase (in my case there are other issues and I have to rewrite the code if you need it ...).